# Problem with Store Dependent Effect Unit-Test

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-test

this is my first approach to unit test effects and I don't know how to write test for my Store Dependent Effect, here is the effect code:

```
validaCellulare$ = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(checkPIvaSuccess, inviaOtpIntent),
            concatMap(action => of(action).pipe(
                withLatestFrom(this.onboardingSelector.modelStep1$)
            )),
            exhaustMap(([action, datiStep1]) =>
                this.onboardingService.postValidateCellulare(datiStep1.cellulare, OnboardingFactory.getCellulareWidgetId(this.centricoState.widgetStep1)).pipe(
                    map((res) => {
                            if (!!res && res.result.status === ApplicationParams.StatusResponse.success) {
                                if (action.type === checkPIvaSuccess.type) {
                                    this.modalService.open(ApplicationParams.templateNames.OTP, {
                                        isClosable: false
                                    });
                                }
                                return inviaOtpSuccess();
                            }
                            return action.type === checkPIvaSuccess.type ? errorThrowing({statusCode: res.result.statusCode}) : inviaOtpIntentError();
                        }
                    ),
                    catchError(() => of(inviaOtpIntentError()))
                )
            )
        ));
```

Above my unit-test:

```
it('checkPIvaSuccess should dispatch inviaOtpSuccess, on success call postValidateCellulare and open modal OTP', () => {
    store.setState({onboarding: {modelStep1: {partitaIva: '12345678960', email: 'fasdfa@sdf.ati', cellulare: '1204014001', flagPrivacy: true}}});
    const mockResponse = Mock.onboarding.validate.cellulare[1].body;
    const action = checkPIvaSuccess({guid: '1592314141805665835746662667089'});
    const completion = inviaOtpSuccess();

    actions$ = hot('a', {a: action});
    const response = cold('(a|)', {a: mockResponse});
    const expected = cold('b', {b: completion});

    onboardingService.postValidateCellulare = jest.fn(() => response);
    expect(effects.validaCellulare$).toBeObservable(expected);
    expect(modalService.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ApplicationParams.templateNames.OTP, {isClosable: false});
});
```

Debugging this code in test environment it's look like blocked inside the concatMap and stop immediatelly without call the internal server call postValidateCellulare. Someone can help me please?

--------------- EDIT NOW IT WORKS -------------

Thanks to @BenLesh I double check my code and I miss to set my `appKeyStore = 'entityCache'`. So replacing the spec as follow it completely works:

```
it('checkPIvaSuccess should dispatch inviaOtpSuccess, on success call postValidateCellulare and open modal OTP', () => {
            store.setState({[appStoreKey]: {onboarding: {modelStep1: {partitaIva: '12345678960', email: 'fasdfa@sdf.ati', cellulare: '1204014001', flagPrivacy: true}}}});
            const mockResponse = Mock.onboarding.validate.cellulare[1].body;
            const action = checkPIvaSuccess({guid: '1592314141805665835746662667089'});
            const completion = inviaOtpSuccess();

            actions$ = hot('a', {a: action});
            const response = cold('(a|)', {a: mockResponse});
            const expected = cold('b', {b: completion});

            onboardingService.postValidateCellulare = jest.fn(() => response);
            expect(effects.validaCellulare$).toBeObservable(expected);
            expect(modalService.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ApplicationParams.templateNames.OTP, {isClosable: false});
        });
```

Comment: It seems like `this.onboardingSelector.modelStep1$` isn't an observable in your test for some reason. I'd set a break point there and check that out.

Comment: Thank you @BenLesh, I check 2 times and I observe that I miss my app store key 'entityCache', so if I call setState as follow it works!